DISCORD BOT - Is it possible to track how long a user is speaking during a session?
I run debates on Discord and need to track how long each user speaks. I have only found the option to track if a user has a microphone turned on, but I haven't found any documentation on tracking active speaking.
Any advice on how to manage my needs is appreciated!
I've been going through the Discord API documentation but can't seem to make sense of it. I can track the time when a user has their microphone on, but I can’t seem to track spoken words for each user.
I found this guildMemberSpeaking but it looks it is not working these days.
